# How to export a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vuex, vue-composition-api

as shown in the below posted code, i want to export the function `GISWSCaller`. i am following the tutorial in [this link](https://logaretm.com/blog/making-the-most-out-of-vuejs-injections/), and i want to create something as in the 3rd code snippet in that link.
the problem i am encountring is, for the below posted code, the VS-codes studio can not recognize the code as valid. i mean the same code posted below when pasted into the VS-codes, it becomes colored in whitw as shonw in the screen shot attached.

please let me know how correctly i should export the code posted below.

**updated code .vue**:

```
import { provide } from 'vue';
let res = undefined

export default function GISWSCaller(){

  async function fetchURL(params){
    console.log("params:",params);
    
    const splitted = params.split(',')
    if (splitted.length == 4) {
      const response = await fetch('https://xx/xx/getDistanceFromOriginToDestination/' + params)
      res =  await response.json()
      return res
    }
    return false
  }
  
const ctx = {
  fetchURL
}

provide('GISWSContext',ctx)
return fetchURL
}
```

**img**:

[image]

Comment: Its return in line 39. Also, maybe VS code is not recognizing this. Try restarting.

Comment: @subodhkalika i set it right now. but still the code is not recognizable by vscodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file extension is wrong. It should be `.js`.
Secondly, you are writing a composable and not a component. So the directory should be named `composables` not `components`.

Comment: morning.i followed the instructions you presupposed, but still i can not use `provide(GISWSContext,ctx`.......i updated my code as shown above ...would you please tell me how to fix it

Comment: can you please tell me how in this tutorial:https://logaretm.com/blog/making-the-most-out-of-vuejs-injections/#use-the-composition-api the author used `provide` inside an exported functio?

Comment: What do you mean how? In the tutorial he used composables, it's a way to extract common code that usually would go into `script setup` into a standalone function. Then in a vue component where you need it you import the function and say `const ctx = useAppUserContext()`and then you have access ctx.

Comment: thank you .but it is still vague to me. the author did not use <script setup>, so how provide can be used then? so sorry for the lake of understanding

Comment: When you have `<script setup>` you are writing a component, when you just have a function you have a composable (if you write vue code in there). `provide` can be used because it's imported `import { provide } from 'vue';` I recommend you read more about [composition api](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#what-is-composition-api) and [composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html).

Comment: but in my code posted above in the question, i also used `import { provide } from 'vue'??!!

Comment: Man, your question was why the code is not highlighted correctly and I'm telling you, your file extension is wrong. It has to be `.js`

Comment: yes. i changed the file extension few days ago and re-posted the code as shown above.but i do not why i cant use `provide` while it is imported in the code

Comment: ` re-posted the code as shown above`? your screenshot still has the wrong extension and saying `i cant use provide while it is imported in the code` doesnt help us at all, we have no clue what doenst work

Comment: you are right, i modified the question.

Comment: please dont modify question so that the answers dont match anymore... rather open a new issue and you still dont describe what does not work. Is there an error or what happens ?

Answer (score 2):

in vue js, components are consists of three parts:

```
<template></template>

<style></style>

<script></script>
```

all your code must be inside this parts.
your file is .vue format, and your code is out of the mentions parts.
put your code inside the script tag, or change file extension to .js to resolve this problem.

[more information](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/sfc.html)

---

edited:

src/utils/GISWSCaller.is

```
let res = undefined

export function useGISWSCaller() {
    async function fetchURL(params) {
        console.log('params:', params);

        const splitted = params.split(',')
        if (splitted.length == 4) {
            const response = await fetch('https://xx/xx/getDistanceFromOriginToDestination/' + params)
            res = await response.json()
            return res
        }
        return false
    }

    const ctx = {
        fetchURL
    }

    return ctx
}
```

src/main.js

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import {useGISWSCaller} from 'GISWSCaller'

const app = createApp({})
const ctx = useGISWSCaller()
app.provide('ctx', ctx)
app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: If I placed my the code I posted above inside the tags you mentioned, will I still be able to export the code as a function?

Comment: for resusing that functions? not specially but you can create a js file, and put your code inside that, so in the mentioned component and another places, use that file. you can export each functions you want and reuse in another module similar vue components, js files or ts files, ....

Comment: thanks, isn't there any way to call `provide` from within a function please?

Comment: better do not do. but i recommend to you  use this method that good for large scale projects:

Comment: can you please tell me how in this tutorial:https://logaretm.com/blog/making-the-most-out-of-vuejs-injections/#use-the-composition-api the author used `provide` inside an exported functio?

Comment: i read the article, the method used is correct, provide and inject methods can be use in anywhere in vue 3 project, if your target is that implement composition API , and use the useGISWSCaller inside vue component or javascript (js or ts) files, you can use provide inside the GISWSCaller function, the mentioned method in the post, recommended for call the method once in global scope while create vue App and also using in components and js files as singleton.

Comment: So sorry, I modified your answer erroneously.sorry again

Comment: its ok. I hope I have helped a little.